# Stuck in a loop while waiting for

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location

I have a set of points, and I want to run a calculation where the user can tap a button and be routed to the point in the set that's nearest to them. The calculation works correctly.

My problem now is that I want the button that does the calculation to only show up when the location accuracy of the device is good enough to provide a good starting point for routing - say, under seventy-five meters of accuracy. However, I keep getting stuck in an infinite loop when trying to check for the accuracy, and haven't found any good alternatives to what I'm trying to do.

Here's my relevant code (and I've tried this as both a while{} and do{} while loop).

```
        do {
        NSLog(@"%f", currentLocation.horizontalAccuracy);
        if (currentLocation.horizontalAccuracy < 75 && currentLocation.horizontalAccuracy != 0)
        {
            NSLog(@"Accuracy is good!");
            calcDistance.hidden = false;
            break;
        }
        else
            continue;
    } while (currentLocation.horizontalAccuracy > 75 || currentLocation.horizontalAccuracy == 0);
```

All that happens when I run the app on a device is a total hang, and in the simulator the log just keeps repeating an accuracy of 0.0000 - I have an NSLog statement in my locationManager that should post the current location info (`NSLog(@"%@", currentLocation);`), but that never shows up in the log.

My guess is that it's getting to the loop before any location updates are occurring, and then it gets stuck there and isn't able to get any further location info. What are some nicer alternatives to these loops that I can take that would make this work smoothly?

Comment: Just put this code (the stuff inside the loop, not the loop itself) inside your `locationManager:didUpdateLocation: method.

Comment: Doing this in a loop will take 100% CPU time and empty the device's battery in the shortest possible time. _That_'s why you need to follow ahruss' recommendation and only do things when the location manager tells you that something has changed.

Comment: Fantastic. It didn't occur to me to run that code inside of the location manager. Makes total sense to me now that I look at it that way. Thanks, you two!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's happening is that the location update comes back on the main run loop, and you're blocking the main run loop with that while loop.

You could put that logic on another thread, but I wouldn't advise it.

I'd suggest putting up an alert with a UIActivityIndicatorView inside of it, and waiting until you receive a location update with the accuracy you need.

Comment: Awesome - I didn't know about the UIActivityIndicator stuff. I'll definitely add that to my reading. I'm very new with this, and some of the basic things escape me still. Much appreciated! ahruss' info above _looks_ like it's working the way I wanted to, but I'll play around and see what works best.